# Solidity Contract Unused Function/Parameter

Tags: solidity

```
function _postValidatePurchase (
    address _beneficiary,
    uint256 _weiAmount
  )
    pure internal
  {
    // optional override
  }
```

When I compile I get this error in parts of my smart contract that mimic the function above: "Warning: Unused function parameter. Remove or comment out the variable name to silence this warning.uint256 _weiAmount". However, when I comment out the uint and weiAmount, I get these errors :

```
DocstringParsingError: Documented parameter "_beneficiary" not found in the parameter list of the function.
DocstringParsingError: Documented parameter "_weiAmount" not found in the parameter list of the function.
libs/openzeppelin/crowdsale/Crowdsale.sol:105:5: TypeError: Wrong argument count for function call: 2 arguments given but expected 0.
_postValidatePurchase(_beneficiary, weiAmount);
```

regarding this line:

```
 _postValidatePurchase(_beneficiary, weiAmount);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

"Warning: Unused function parameter" is not an error, just a warning. If you have a function with parameters you are not using inside the function, why do you need them? You can just remove them from the input. The only case I can think of is when you are overriding the function. In any case, a warning does not prevent the contract from being compiled. You can just ignore the warning.

Comment: if the User asks something then it most likely he really needs it, you can't foresee all the reasons with a human brain, it is a very limited device. For example, I am writing a test for a token contract and I need to call `mint()` function but mint takes two parameters, which I won't really be using in the test since I am going to issue a revert() right from the start, but the standard for the token requires passing the arguments to the function. This is why we need a way to remove this annoying warning.